# Traktor Audio 10 as default output device?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm trying to use my Traktor Audio Interface as standard output device.
Under Windows this is really simple but so far I couldn't get it working.

My first try was to use this [alsa config](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1345211#p1345211) and to define it as default like this:

```
pcm.!default {
   type plug
   slave.pcm T10_pair1
}

ctl.!default {
    type plug
    slave.pcm T10_pair1
}
```

I can use it by specifying the audio device but my default clause seems to have no effect.

> mpg123 -a T10_pair1 ./sound.mp3 # this plays via Traktor Audio
>
> mpg123 -a default ./sound.mp3 # this still plays via my onboard sound card

PulseAudio detects the Traktor Audio 10 but doesn't let me choose it as output device.

[image: pavucontrol Configuration]
[image: pavucontrol Output Devices]

[list-cards output](http://pastebin.com/fiAmAryJ)

[list-sinks output](http://pastebin.com/4XwWQrbW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've the exact same problem. Use the following shell command :

```
pactl load-module module-detect
```

Then your device should appear in the output list.

Comment: This works but I have to do it after every restart.
Have you found a way to permanently set Traktor Audio as default audio interface?

Comment: Try to edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and add "load-module module-detect"

Comment: It is already in the config, sadly didn't fix the problem. I'll accept your answer but will accept another answer that persists the fix across reboots.

Comment: To run on every startup, you can use `Startup Applications` and specify the module detect. (https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)